# How can i compare if a text line starts with a word in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-extraction

I have a key text "Outros" and a text file im reading and enumerating. I need to print only the lines that starts with that key. Is it possible?

Im alreadying printing lines, but it prints every line that has this key inside the line, not only the start. I really have no idea of how i can do this.

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if a in line:
        print(line.rstrip())
    if b in line:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: A string object has the method `startswith` for that.

Answer (score 3):

```py
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('Outros'):
        print(line)
```